# Java : inherits a generic type

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extend from Generic Supertype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000478/extend-from-generic-supertype)

Hi everyone.
I come from C++ and I loooved working with templates.
I would like, in Java, to "insert" a node into the inheritance tree at a particular point.
... I think code would be more explicit :

```
public class MyClass<E> extends E {}
```

It would work fine with C++ templates but java gives me a "cannot refere to type parameter as supertype". Is there a way to do that in java ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Java generics are NOT C++ templates.  The concepts are not in any useful compatible.  You are in for a world of frustration and compiler warnings if you don't divorce the two ideas as a soon as possible.  The only purpose of generics in Java is to prevent ClassCastException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the problem with the code you tried, consider what would happen if `E` were, say, `Integer`?

You can do what you want with nodes that contain generic data:

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    // other tree bookkeeping fields
}
```

Then you can define subclasses:

```
public class ThreadedTreeNode<T> extends Node<T> {
    // even more bookkeeping fields
}
```

Comment: If the generic Type T of your parent class extends something (Serializable, Comparable,...) then the children should do it as well... such as: `class ThreadedTreeNode<T extends Comparable> extends Node<T>` where `class Node<T extends Comparable>`

Comment: I don't see a problem with `Integer` - aside from that `Integer` is final.  That doesn't seem like a problem with the construction, just your choice of type.  It just means you can't use `final` classes for `E`.  Granted, Java would likely need a way to express that as a bound on the type parameter, for clarity, but that's not really a *problem*, per se, just annoying.  Is there a more fundamental reason why type parameters can't be used as superclasses?

Comment: @Erhannis - There are all sorts of other problems. Basically, if you don't know the superclass, the compiler has no idea whether a method declaration is legal in the subclass. (It might turn out that a `final` method of the superclass was being overridden.) Checking all that when binding generic types suddenly becomes an exponentially harder problem for the compiler. And that's just one example off the top of my head. In the subclass, what is `super`? How is the compiler supposed to generate byte code for stuff like that when the superclass is unknown?

Comment: @TedHopp I suppose that's fair - type erasure would kinda conflict with actually compiling your code.  Whether or not the issue is logically irreconcilable, I concede that allowing the construct in question would significantly complicate many things, and would only rarely be useful, anyway.

Comment: This is composition, not inheritance which is what Ted asks for.